# Drag and Drop value from one cell to another in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I need to create the following UI design, this is basically converting the google sheet work to the web application to manage the inventory.

I have a table listing quantity of products, this is the order placed by a shopkeeper.

This order can be shipped in various pick list by the manufacturer.

1. The pick list needs to generate by using drag and drop functionality.
2. The total value of the item in all the picks and the remaining column of the order must be equal to the ordered quantity.
3. On dragging the quantity remaining to the particular pick list the value entered in the pick list must be subtracted from the remaining column.
4. We can also drag and drop the item values within the pick list also.

I have attached the screenshots to depict the flow of information.

Can anybody guide me regarding the approach to be taken for the above-mentioned scenario.
We are using Angular 2 framework.

## Screen 1

[image: screen1]

## Screen 2

[image: screen2]

## Screen 3

[image: screen3]